# Have Cryptsetup Benchmark --cipher run through list of all ciphers

Tags: cryptsetup, dm-crypt

I'm trying to run `cryptsetup benchmark --cipher` on the entire list of ciphers included in `/proc/crypto`.

I obtained the list from `/proc/crypto` by doing the following:

`cd ./Documents/; cat /proc/crypto | grep "name" | cut -c 16- | tee ciphers.txt`

Now, I'm trying to find a way to pass each cipher, one by one, through to `cryptsetup`. My first attempt was simply `cat ciphers.txt | cryptsetup benchmark --cipher`, but now I am thinking I might need to convert the list I created to a .CSV file and pass it in via a `for` loop.

Is there a way to use the `ciphers.txt` list I've created, without too much effort, to pass through to `cryptsetup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with dm_crypt. It's a simple shell programming question.

**First, you are committing** [cat abuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat). Instead of `cat /proc/crypto | grep "name"`, simply write `grep name /proc/crypto` (no quotation marks required).

You could also combine the grep and cut into a single `sed` command. Not necessarily easier to read: `sed -n '/^name/s/.*: //p' /proc/crypto` but requires a single command instead of two. `-n` prevents `sed` from printing lines by default. The program finds lines that start with "name" and strips the first part of the line until the blank after the colon. `p` ensures that this is then printed.

**Let's now address your question**. I understand that the `--cipher` option takes a single cipher. This means that you have to run `cryptsetup benchmark` several times, once per cipher. This requires a loop, for example:

```
for cipher in $(<cipher.txt)
do cryptsetup benchmark --cipher "$cipher"
done
```

The quotation marks are necessary since some cipher names contain special characters such as parentheses.

If you don't need the file `cipher.txt`, you could do all this in one go:

```
for cipher in $(grep name /proc/crypto | cut -c 16-)
do cryptsetup benchmark --cipher "$cipher"
done
```

Comment: An alternative to `cut`: using `awk` for the ciphers: `awk '/^name/ {print $3}' < /proc/crypto`.